# Convert from Single/Stack to Basket

Tags: r, market-basket-analysis

Firstly, I saw a posting for a conversion from basket to single but not the reverse, and I saw another, similar posting that was never answered.

I have data in stack form like so:

```
ID  Product
A    Prod1
A    Prod2
B    Prod1
B    Prod2
B    Prod3
C    Prod1
```

I need it to look like this:

```
ID   Products
A    Prod1, Prod2
B    Prod1, Prod2, Prod3
C    Prod1
```

I tried `unstack` then `unlist` but those didn't work.

How do you convert from single to basket?

Comment: What exactly is the structure of your desired output? Are you "baskets" just strings (ie `"Prod1, Prod2, Prod3"`)?

Comment: Yes, they are just strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up where @MrFlick left off, if you want to convert your rows to columns, you can do so, but you'll need to add a "time" variable to your data first. This is easily done with `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package.

From there, you can use your preferred method to go from a "long" dataset to a "wide" one. For instance, here I've shown how to use the `reshape` function from base R and `dcast.data.table` from the "data.table" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
reshape(getanID(mydf, "ID"), direction = "wide", idvar = "ID", timevar = ".id")
#    ID Product.1 Product.2 Product.3
# 1:  A     Prod1     Prod2        NA
# 2:  B     Prod1     Prod2     Prod3
# 3:  C     Prod1        NA        NA
dcast.data.table(getanID(mydf, "ID"), ID ~ .id, value.var = "Product", fill = "")
#    ID     1     2     3
# 1:  A Prod1 Prod2      
# 2:  B Prod1 Prod2 Prod3
# 3:  C Prod1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to collapse into strings, try

```
aggregate(Product~ID, dd, paste)
```

(assuming your data.frame is named `dd`). That will return

```
#   ID             Product
# 1  A        Prod1, Prod2
# 2  B Prod1, Prod2, Prod3
# 3  C               Prod1
```

Comment: I'm curious: where do the commas come from?

Comment: Well, it's actually `aggregate()` that's collapsing the result. If you wanted to change the delimiter, you could use `aggregate(Product~ID, dd, paste, collapse=":")`.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of using aggregate this way.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it also possible to alphabetize the list?  I only thought of this just now.

Comment: Also, what if I want to put the items in separate columns?

Comment: @Cinji18 If you want to sort, you could do `aggregate(Product~ID, dd, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=":"))`. If you want columns, that's a completely different type of problem. You can search for other questions about reshaping your data from long to wide format. Comments are not a good place to ask questions different from your original post.